# Gap between recyclerview items after dismissing an item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, recyclerview-layout, itemtouchhelper

I was experimenting with the recyclerview trying to learn how to allow a swipe dismiss with an item in the view. Whenever I dismiss an item, the space the item used to take up is still there with an empty space. The items won't move up to populate the empty space.

[Screenshot of empty space](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/BNXwfBkDmIjuPMSGh9baMqGB2JVRU7MJ2vFneRDn5cmYeSKccqGxq5n9a8jl3BkGaZmWAD_JteWrZxICAHMQE1yPw0k=s960)

Is there something I am missing? (I am using Xamarin, but the solution, I assume, is practically the same as if I were using java)

Here is the Recyclerview adapter with eh ItemTouchHelperAdapter

```
public class NoteAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, IItemTouchHelperAdapter
{
    public NoteObject[] notes;
    public Context c;

    public override int ItemCount => notes.Length;
    public override long GetItemId(int position) => position;

    public class NoteViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View MainView { get; set; }
        public CardView MainCView { get; set; }
        public TextView TitleView { get; set; }
        public TextView MessageView { get; set; }
        public NoteViewHolder(View v) : base(v) { }
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View noteCard = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.NoteCardView, parent, false);
        CardView cView = (CardView)noteCard.FindViewById(Resource.Id.noteCard);
        TextView titleView = (TextView)noteCard.FindViewById(Resource.Id.noteTitle);
        TextView messageView = (TextView)noteCard.FindViewById(Resource.Id.noteMessage);

        return new NoteViewHolder(noteCard) { TitleView = titleView, MessageView = messageView, MainCView = cView };
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        NoteViewHolder noteHolder = (NoteViewHolder)holder;

        noteHolder.MainCView.Click += (sender, e) => 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(c, typeof(NoteReview));
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.PutString(c.GetString(Resource.String.noteBundleKey), notes[position].ToString()); 
            b.PutInt(c.GetString(Resource.String.noteIDBundleKey), position);
            i.PutExtra(c.GetString(Resource.String.intentKey), b);
            c.StartActivity(i);
        };

        noteHolder.MainCView.LongClick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
            alert.SetTitle(Resource.String.dialogTitle);

            alert.SetPositiveButton(Resource.String.delete, (dSender, dE) => { Firebase.DeleteAt(position); });
            alert.SetNeutralButton(Resource.String.cancel, (dSender, dE) => {});

            Dialog d = alert.Create();
            d.Window.SetType(WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);

            MainActivity.StartDialog(d);
        };

        noteHolder.TitleView.Text = notes[position].Title;
        noteHolder.MessageView.Text = notes[position].Message;
    }

    public bool OnItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) => true;

    public void OnItemDismiss(int position)
    {
        Firebase.DeleteAt(position);
        notes = Firebase.GetNotes();
        NotifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

Here is the callback

```
    public class NoteSwipeHandler : SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback
{
    IItemTouchHelperAdapter recAdapter { get; set; }

    public NoteSwipeHandler(IItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) : base(adapter)
    {
        recAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public override bool IsLongPressDragEnabled => true;
    public override bool IsItemViewSwipeEnabled => true;

    public override bool OnMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target)
    {
        recAdapter.OnItemMove(source.AdapterPosition, target.AdapterPosition);
        return true;
    }

    public override void OnSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i)
    {
        recAdapter.OnItemDismiss(viewHolder.AdapterPosition);
    }
}
```

The Xamarin library I'm using for the item touch helper is [this](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinItemTouchHelper)

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: After swyping away, are you removing the item from the adapter?

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the middle of editing it, and I had to leave the house. I'm kinda new to this. @MohamdAl-Najjar

Answer (score 0):

The thing is after you swiped the item, the item from the UI is gone and the item in adapter. But there is a vacant space in your list and that's why you have a blank space.

I assume you have a list of those objects in the activity and in the adapter.

Remove the item from the list in adapter using

```
list.remove(position);
```

Then have a method in your adapter

```
public void updateList(List<Lists> lists){
this.lists = lists;
notifyItemSetChanged();
}
```

This code is in java. So please convert it into Xamarin.

And finally, call this method in the callback when swiped

```
adapter.updateList(list);
```

I hope this helps.